# can I add values into a column conditionally in mysql via a query (heidisql)?

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I'm having trouble inserting values conditionally into a column via a query. I am trying to add the following: low, med, high into a new column called income_level which is based on the value in column income. What i wish to query:

INSERT INTO chile

VALUE ('low_income' if income < 10000, 'medium_income' if income BETWEEN 10000 AND 100000, 'high_income' if income >100000)

Current state of the table

| ID | income |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7000 |
| 2 | 15000 |

Wished state of the table

| ID | Income | Income_level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7000 | low_income |
| 2 | 15000 | medium_income |
| 3 | 110000 | high_income |

I have been searching around stackoverflow and searching for an answer but haven't found a applicable solution that I could've used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest making `income_level` a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html), so you don't have to insert a value. Also you don't have to worry if you update the `income` that the `income_level` becomes out of sync.

```
ALTER TABLE chile ADD COLUMN income_level VARCHAR(20)
  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN income < 10000 THEN 'low_income'
                            WHEN income > 100000 THEN 'high_income'
                            ELSE 'medium_income' END);
```